# Integer values are not changing

Tags: python

I am making a game. The life points (`LP`) counter starts an 0 and changes throughout the game. when I run it the life points don't change.

My code is:

```
LP = 100
print("You are in a battle game")
print("Depending on you actions changes your life points")
print("All answers are lower case")
print("Life points start at 100")
print("You die when life points reach 0")
print("Good Luck!")
print(" ")
print(" ")
print(" ")
print(" ")
print(" ")
print("You are in an aircraft...")
print("There are no parachutes in sight...")
print("The planes is landing...")
print("Once on the floor you are in battle")
print("What do you do? (2 chances)")
print("a = Jump with no parachute")
print("b = Get off when plane lands")
print("c = Start the fight")
counta = 1
while counta <= 3:
    aa = str(input())
    if aa == ("a"):
        print("You landed feet first in a deep lake...")
        print("Hurts but you are alive")
        LP - 8
        print("You have", LP, "life points remaining.")
        print("Do you want to change your decision? yes OR no")
        aaa = str(input())
        if aaa == ("yes"):
            LP + 8
            print("Last chance. Re-answer the question. a, b OR c")
            counta += 1
        elif aaa == ("no"):
            break
        else:
             print("That was not an option.")
        break
    elif aa == ("b"):
            print("There is a little fist fight as you try to escape...")
            print("You get punched but get away ok")
            LP - 12
            print("You have", LP, "life points remaining.")
            print("Do youwant to change your decision? yes OR no")
            aab = str(input())
    if aab ==("yes"):
            LP + 12
            print("Last chance. Re-answer the question. a, b OR c")
            counta += 1
    elif aab == ("no"):
            break
    else:
            print("That was not an option")
            break
print(LP)
```

Why does the counter not work?

Comment: `LP - 8` calculates the result of that expression and returns. You then do nothing with the returned value...

Comment: just like @Tomerikoo says, you're not actually changing the value of `LP` anywhere.                                                                                   Wherever you have `LP - 8`, you should instead be using `LP -= 8`, similarly for `+`, just like how you have been modifying the value of `counta`

Comment: I'm voting to close this as typo/can't be reproduced...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you try and change the value of an integer (In this instance your LP variable) you need to declare the variable change first. So every time the value should change add `LP =` in front. So:

```
LP = LP - 8
```

for example

Answer (score 1):

`LP - somenumber` is an expression. That expression has a value. If you want the `LP` variable to have that value, you need to assign it back to `LP`. For example, `LP = LP - 5`

Answer (score 1):

The reason your program is not working is because you are not actually changing the value of the variable LP

For example, instead of using

```
LP + 8
```

You would need to say

```
LP += 8
```

To add 8 to the variable LP

Comment: Saying `LP += 8` is the same as `LP = LP + 8`, so this works. The other answers also describe the same method.

Comment: Ok. Maybe I did something wrong ... I'm using old python version (on my brothers old laptop) and i'm very new so i'll try it again. Your method looks a lot cleaner than the others.